# Boost win compile: int32_t is not a member of global namespace

Tags: c++, boost

While trying to compile boost libraries on windows 8.1 I'm getting this error:

```
error C2039: 'int32_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

from `boost\cstdint.hpp`

Here's what I did:

- downloaded the source
- launched `bootstrap.bat`
- launched `b2 toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage`

Does anyone know what may be the cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: What version of Visual C++?  For `int32_t`, the code must first `#include <inttypes.h>`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It should compile without any additional includes. Freakk please write what version of VC++ and Boost do you use. If you have a problem with Boost consider asking the developers on the Boost-users mailing list: http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-users or report a bug: http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html

Comment: @BenVoigt: `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`, no?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Well, "The `<inttypes.h>` header shall include the `<stdint.h>` header." and "The `<stdint.h>` header is a subset of the `<inttypes.h>` header" so probably either works.

Comment: Boost version is 1.55.0, VC++ 2012. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Are you compiling from within a vsvars32 set up command prompt?

Comment: I saw something like this before, don't remember details. It was related somehow with MinGW I had on my disk. Either boost was using wrong <inttypes.h> from MinGW or I deliberately configured paths to use it from MingGW.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem compiling a fresh unzip of the Boost 1.56.0 Regex library with Visual Studio 2010:

```
...\VC\INCLUDE\cwchar(33) : error C2039: 'wcscat' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

It turns out I had inadvertently modified some of the core include files under my VS2010 `VC\include` folder. Some files had been modified during a *Replace in files* on a solution.

I used the Win7 *Previous Versions* tab to restore the original files and it now compiles fine.

This problem can arise when you have **write access** to the core library files, e.g.

- You are running the IDE as an administrator; or
- You have installed Visual Studio somewhere other than `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Those standard locations have special default file and folder security (Access Control Lists) that prevent this kind of mistake occurring when running as a limited user.

(My problem was due to the latter; and I have since applied more restrictive file and folder ACLs to all my bespoke application-related folders to protect me when running as a limited user).